# Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I've been searching some answers for that problems that occurs while I'm trying to access a page baked with CakePHP, and I'm still getting this error :

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Billet. user_id' in 'field list'

Here's the query created by Cake

```
SELECT `Billet`.`id` AS `Billet__id`, 
`Billet`.`created` AS `Billet__created`, 
`Billet`.`updated` AS `Billet__updated`, 
`Billet. user_id` AS `Billet__ user_id`,
`Billet`.`title` AS `Billet__title`, 
`Billet`.`tags` AS `Billet__tags`, 
`Billet`.`content` AS   `Billet__content`, 
`Users`.`id` AS `Users__id`, 
`Users`.`username` AS `Users__username`, 
`Users`.`password` AS `Users__password`, 
`Users`.`name` AS `Users__name`,
`Users`.`lastname` AS `Users__lastname`, 
`Users`.`birthdate` AS `Users__birthdate`, 
`Users`.`email` AS `Users__email` FROM `billet`
`Billet` INNER JOIN `users` `Users` ON `Users`.`id` = (`Billet. user_id`) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

The code that does the query is directly baked by Cake, so I don't have any lines to show how the query's done.

Comment: Please show any code you are using in Cake PHP that creates the query...

Comment: Something is definitely adding a space in this `Billet__ user_id` and `Billet. user_id`.

Comment: As I said below, the code is directly baked by Cake, so I don't think (after checking I'm sure I don't have any explicit code for the query) there's any code from me that interferes

Comment: @DevNewb if there happens to be a `\n` in Cake's code somewhere that is generating your query, then that could also account for the space(s). I've never heard of such behaviour before, unless there was some kind of alteration done to some code somewhere.

Comment: The column name in your database may contain the leading whitespace.

Comment: I'll be checking that tomorrow, thanks for the answers, it'll be probably the space thing, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing ticks on this line, and you have an extra space in the `AS` name:

```
`Billet. user_id` AS `Billet__ user_id`,
```

It should be

```
`Billet`.`user_id` AS `Billet__user_id`,
```

Same goes for this line:

```
`Billet` INNER JOIN `users` `Users` ON `Users`.`id` = (`Billet. user_id`) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

which should be

```
`Billet` INNER JOIN `users` `Users` ON `Users`.`id` = (`Billet`.`user_id`) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I change that, considering Cake is doing it automatically ?

Comment: Good question. Show how you're assembling your Cake query.

Comment: I'm afraid Cake is doing it natively, if I don't fool myself, I don't have any explicit lines that shows how the query is done.

Comment: How about the code that you're using that would start this query? Something that tells Cake to get the Users and Billets?

Comment: I think I just did something wrong somewhere, I'll be doing it again from scratch, I'm tagging it resolved for now, thanks !